# How to get value from firebse remote config in my web?

Tags: javascript, firebase-remote-config

I created a firebase project and created a remote config to place setting values, but I cannot read it in my web, the console says it is empty

This is my code and console result
Are there any errors?

**html:**

```
<body>   
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
    <script>
     
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "...",
            authDomain: "...",
            databaseURL: "...",
            projectId: "...",
            storageBucket: "...",
            messagingSenderId: "...",
            appId: "...",
            measurementId: "..."
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
        const remoteConfig = firebase.remoteConfig();

        var version = remoteConfig.getValue("version");
        console.log('version', version);

   

   
    </script>
</body>
```

console result

[image]

Comment: Hello @rubie, Can you increase the fetch interval?

Comment: remoteConfig.settings.minimumFetchIntervalMillis = 3600000;

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch and activate values before call `remoteConfig.getValue("version");`

```
remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
  .then(() => {
    var version = remoteConfig.getValue("version");
    console.log('version', version);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=web#fetch-and-activate-values_1